# How to insert the range of numbers to an array by iterating through it?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, c++11, insert

I am making a program, in which I need to iterate the numbers, starting from `1` to `num` then put the value of that array `{1...num`} to a variable that can be called in the `for` loop.

This is where I am at.

```
int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    cin >> num;

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
    {
        procnum[i];
    }
}
```

I need `procnum[num]` to have a value like ...

```
int procnum[num] = {1,2,3...num};
```

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your question? Its not clear what you are asking

Comment: BTW: `for (int i=1;i<=num;i++)` -> `for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)`. In C++ array indexes start at 0, not at 1.

Comment: I sorted it out Thanks to Trantor's reply for (int a=0;a<=num;a++)
 {
  procnum[a]=a+1;
 }

Answer (score 3):

If you can use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [std::iota](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota), this is just two line code.

No need to for(index) loop the array. **[See live example here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CiX5NRNRaSO36vrA)**

```
#include <vector>   // std::vector
#include <numeric>  // std::iota

std::vector<int> procnum(some_size);
std::iota(procnum.begin(), procnum.end(), 1);
```

Comment: Sorry, but its a perfect way to confuse beginners.

Comment: @Trantor If a beginner doesn't learn something new every day, he will remain always a beginner. Just for the remark. ;)

Answer (score 2):

In C++11, no need to even write a loop, unless you need to do error checking (e.g. check that reading input succeeded, or that the input value is valid).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm> 

int main()
{
     int size;
     std::cin >> size;

     std::vector<int> procnum(size);

     std::iota(procnum.begin(), procnum.end(), 1);    // starting value is 1

     //  output vector to demonstrate it is populated

     std::copy(procnum.begin(), procnum.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout," ");
     std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Before C++11, there was no algorithm `std::iota()`, but it is possible to use `std::generate()` and a simple functor to achieve the same effect.

Comment: *no need to even write a loop* : well *range based loops* are not that much bad to use. At least you sure about no out of bound UB happens, like in index-based iteration.

Comment: @JeJo - I'm not suggesting loops are bad.  Just that they are not needed in this case.   There are also often benefits in using standard algorithms instead of writing loops to achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to create dynamic arrays:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int size;
    std::cin >> size;

    std::vector<int> procnum(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        procnum[i] = i + 1;
    }
}
```

---

you shouldn't `use namespace std;` - read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) why.

Comment: Using namespaces in source files is not a bad idea at all, as some answers clearly stated. However, the most upvoted answers could be miss-interpreted ...

Comment: for me personally I really like saying `std::` as it clearly says that I'm using some utility from the STL. Besides, this can be more time saving than not typing `std::` if that is someones arguing.